# Docker mount a volume as root

Tags: linux, docker, containers, linux-containers

**The problem description**

I have a Docker image, which is being executed with volume mounting options a large number of times. It is built in a way so that the default user does not have root permissions. However I need to make sure that when I mount the volume it is being mounted as `root` and not as the current working user because of security concerns. (The current working non-root user must not be allowed to delete any files inside the mounted volume.)

**Example**

*From the host machine:*

`docker run -it -v /path/to/mount:/container/mounting/path image-name`

*Inside the container* `current-user@docker-container`:

All of the files inside `/container/mounting/path` must have owner permissions `root root` and not `current-user current-user`.

Comment: You may run into container privilege issues, in which case you can either add the right capability or use `docker run -privileged`