# Docker volume option create folder as "root" user

Tags: linux, docker, docker-volume, docker-container

I am logged in in my PC (Fedora 24) as `rperez`. I have setup Docker for being able to run through this user, so I am running a container as follow:

```
$ docker run -d \
             -it \
             -e HOST_IP=192.168.1.66 \
             -e PHP_ERROR_REPORTING='E_ALL & ~E_STRICT' \
             -p 80:80 \
             -v ~/var/www:/var/www \
             --name php55-dev reypm/php55-dev
```

Notice the `$` sign meaning I am running the command as a non root user (which uses `#`). The command above creates the following directory: `/home/rperez/var/www` but owner is set to `root` I believe this is because `docker` run as `root` user behind scenes.

Having this setup I am not able to create a file under `~/var/www` as `rperez` because the owner is `root` so ...

What is the right way to deal with this? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397548/how-to-give-non-root-user-in-docker-container-access-to-a-volume-mounted-on-the) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097455/docker-mount-a-volume-as-root) but is not so helpful.

Any help?

Comment: Do you mean `chown $(whoami) /path/to/your/dir`?

Comment: @kxxoling I know that's the right command but why should I need to run such command on every directory created by Docker all the time? Should be a command or a flag or a work around to avoid this and that's what I am looking for :)

Comment: You can create the volume directory before running the container, so the directory will be owned by current user.

Comment: I found a discussion here: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3206 It's an expected behavior. You can get a solution there, but I think my way is easier to use.

Comment: @kxxoling Creating the directory first did works pls answer this with your solution so I can accept your answer and thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As discussioned [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3206), this is an expected behavior of docker. You can create the target volume directory before running docker command or change the owner to your current user after the directory is created by docker:

```
chown $(whoami) -R /path/to/your/dir
```

Answer (score 1):

I hit this same issue (also in a genomics context for the very same reason) and also found it quite unintuitive. What is the recommended way to "inherit ownership". Sorry if this described elsewhere, but I couldn't find it. Is it something like:

```
docker run ... -u $(id -u):$(id -g) ...
```